# How to build or run a specific Rust binary project in Atom?

Tags: rust, atom-editor

I am using multiple main files using a single Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "rust_example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [""]

[dependencies]

[[bin]]
name = "main"
path = "src/main.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "fibonachi"
path = "src/fibonachi/main.rs"
```

I tested on console

```
cargo run --bin main` and `cargo run --bin fibonachi
```

And it compiles correctly.

I installed Atom along with several plugins (build, build-cargo, busy, language-rust, linter). When I compile with Atom, it shows these lines:

```
error: `cargo run` requires that a project only have one executable; use the `--bin` option to specify which one to run
error: `cargo run` requires that a project only have one executable; use the `--bin` option to specify which one to run
```

I can't find how to specify which binary I'd like to build from within Atom.

Comment: there's no such option, you can file a bug report at https://github.com/AtomBuild/atom-build-cargo

Comment: It's "fibonacci", by the way.